# How can I get email.utils.formataddr to show a sender name with twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail?

Tags: python, email, smtp, twisted, mime

When I use the standard smtplib.SMTP.sendmail function, I can call it using email.utils.formataddr(senderName, local-part@domain) as the from_addr to show the sender's name in an email client.

When I use twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail to do the same, instead of senderName showing up, I get local-part.

So far I've only tested this in Gmail, but since that's what my company uses, it's part of my requirement.

I've tried sending the formatted address via twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail and get a parse error.

I've used twisted.mail.smtp.quoteaddr, but discovered that just strips the formatted name and address back down to the address.  No parsing error though.

```
        #print('populate the message')
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg["Subject"] = 'A Subject'
        msg["From"] = email.utils.formataddr(('Sender Name', 'noreply@example.com'))
        msg["Reply-to"] = 'noreply@example.com'
        msg["To"] = 'recipient@example.com'
        content = MIMEText("Hey, what's up?" ,"html")
        msg.attach(content)
        msg_timeout = round(float(30))

        # create the sender and send it
        result = twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail("mail-sc", msg["From"], msg["To"].split(","), msg,
                     port=25, requireAuthentication=False)
```

getting this error  Failure: twisted.mail._except.AddressError: Parse error at ' ' of ('"Sender Name" ', [' ', '<','noreply', '@','sender', '.','com', '>'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one standard and syntax for "email addresses".  The standard and syntax for the address used by *SMTP* is (currently) RFC 5321.  This is the kind of address you pass to `twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail`.  The standard and syntax for the address used by *MIME* is (currently) RFC 5322.  This is the kind of address you put into a MIME message for the sender, recipient, cc, etc.

RFC 5321 addresses don't *have* a sender name component.  RFC 5322 addresses do.  I expect that `email.utils.formataddr` is returning a valid RFC 5322 address and it is correct to put this into `msg["From"]`.  However, you must pass RFC 5321 addresses to `twisted.mail.smtp.sendmail`.  Roughly, these are in the format `noreply@example.com`.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul  I appreciate the explanation.  Is there anything on the horizon with Twisted that will support RFC 5322 addresses?

Comment: For what?  It only makes sense for MIME generation which isn't particularly close to Twisted's focus.  You can generate MIME messages however you like and send them with twisted.mail.  You just have to use the correct kind of addresses in each place.

Comment: To be extra clear, it doesn't matter to twisted.mail what's *in* the MIME message.  You can have any kind of addresses you like in the message.  You only have to pass the right kind of address to the `sendmail` call.  It doesn't have to be the same address as is in the message.  They're separate, unrelated layers for separate, unrelated purposes.

Comment: Got it now.  Thanks for your patience.  I was confusing the 2 layers.  Twisted is a great tool and I appreciate all the work you've done for it.